# Best approach to make these circlet wings

Tags: mesh, geometry

I've had a few cracks at making this mesh but it comes out as a mess, not a neat mesh. I've got the circlet section done fine, but these wings on the sides are a bit of a pain for me. If someone has some spare time, could you give me a quick walk through for making odd shapes like this neatly?

[image]

Since it's curved, I've been trying to make it flat, then using *Shrinkwrap* modifier to make sure it matches the curve of the circlet. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it sort of works. I just need to know a better approach to making these wing shapes.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a flat shape with this kind of topology:

[image]

Create a lattice, scale it to fit the mesh size and change its resolution:

[image]

Give a *Lattice* modifier to your object with the lattice as *Object*:

[image]

Switch your lattice to *Edit* mode and deform it:

[image]

Comment: Thats got it, thank you. :) Just trying to keep my geo not trash at the moment while I get better. :)